# Tensorflow could not detect my RTX 3050 notebook GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

Tensorflow could not detect available GPU.

I am working on image classification using below module and notebook (local) spec;

- Python 3.11.X
- Tensorflow 2.12.X
- CUDA 11.8
- cuDNN 8.6
- CPU: Ryzen 5
- GPU: RTX 3050 notebook

However Tensorflow could not see my available GPU, see below information;

[No GPU Available Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94sPh.jpg)

```
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')))

# output
Num GPUs Available:  0
```

I also already added environmental variables;

[Path Variable Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCJzD.jpg)

Anyone have solution on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your path variable screenshot, it seems like you got Windows OS on your laptop.
Tensorflow, however, **does not support** their GPU-based library for Windows after **Tensorflow 2.10**.
Refer to the website for further details: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#gpu

Comment: Many thanks, I did not know about TF 2.12 is not supporting native GPU on window. Now I reinstall TF and python to the compatibility version and that works, appreciate your support.